# active directory not allowing windows login however allows remote desktop

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-authentication

Active directory on my server 2012 r2 server is rejecting logins on my windows 10 professional clients. Each time it is presenting failed authentication "username and password do not match". The server is allowing remote desktop logins with the same credentials from the same computer though if the user uses a local profile instead to bypass the windows (active directory) authentication.

I have managed to get one of my 2 computers to finally work by registering the computer to a workgroup; restarting; changing computer name; restarting; then reregistering it to the domain; then restarting. I am unsure why it is working on that computer now, however, the same procedure is not fixing the second computer.

I am positive the credentials do match what is listed on the server and it does have a connection to the server actively.

is this a known bug; how can I fix this?

Comment: Are your clocks sufficiently in sync?

Comment: `The server is allowing remote desktop logins with the same credentials from the same computer though if the user uses a local profile instead to bypass the windows (active directory) authentication.` - This doesn't quite make sense to me. You can't log onto the local machine with an AD account. You either log onto the domain from this computer with an AD account or you log onto the local machine with a local account. Can you clarify that statement?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing the credentials against ADUC not the local machine.

> domain\username

You can log into the machine using local credentials then use remote desktop to get to the machine so no issues other then the way you are logging in locally. Unless you have errors in the logs after joining the domain.